# Text of item in itemized list is on a separate line from the bullet point

Tags: itemize, minipage

In this MWE, the text of item 2 is on a separate line from the bullet point as shown in the attached image of the output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,changepage, mwe}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item This is item 1. \lipsum[66] 

\item \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\columnsep}\vspace{0pt}%
    \raggedright
    This is item 2 \lipsum[66]
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\columnsep}\vspace{0pt}%
    \raggedright
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}

\item This is item 3. \lipsum[66]

\end{itemize}
```

[image]

**Question: How can I ensure the minipages start on the same line as the bullet point?**

Comment: Remove the `\vspace{0pt}` from the _first_ `minipage` environment?

Comment: @WillieWong thanks, but then the image isn't aligned properly.

Comment: How do you want the image aligned?

Comment: With the first line of text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should be closer to the expected output. Additionally to the alignment of the item and the image, I also made sure, the two minipages fit into the available space, since the original MWE caused an overfull box warning. (Red lines in the following screenshot indicate margins)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % provides the valign option

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item This is item 1. \lipsum[66] 

\item \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-.5\columnsep}
    \raggedright
    This is item 2 \lipsum[66]
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-.5\columnsep}
    \raggedright
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}

\item This is item 3. \lipsum[66]

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```